# How can I use .NET Core FirebaseAdminSdk for Unit Testing with Moq

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, asp.net-core-webapi, firebase-admin

I have been working on .NET Core FirebaseAdminSdk. I want to write unit tests for my own services that are using FirebaseApp class.
FirebaseApp is a sealed class and there is not any interface to moq it.

Is there any way to mock FirebaseApp instance?

```
private readonly Mock<IFirebaseApp> firebaseApp = new Mock<IFirebaseApp>();
```

I need an interface something like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea to try to mock sealed classes like FirebaseApp, because they are designed to be used in a specific way and mocking them can lead to unexpected behavior and make it difficult to test your code correctly.

Instead of trying to mock FirebaseApp, you can use a technique called "dependency injection" to make it easier to test your code. Here's how it works:

1. Create an interface that defines the methods and properties that you need from `FirebaseApp`. For example:

```
    public interface IFirebaseApp
    {
        string Name { get; }
        FirebaseAppOptions Options { get; }
        Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync(bool forceRefresh);
        void Delete();
    }
```

2. Modify your code to accept an instance of IFirebaseApp through its
   constructor or a property, rather than creating a new instance of
   FirebaseApp directly. This is called "dependency injection".
3. In your unit tests, create a mock implementation of IFirebaseApp
   using a mocking framework like Moq. Then pass an instance of the
   mock to your code when you create an instance of your service.

This will allow you to easily control the behavior of FirebaseApp in your tests, and make it easier to test different scenarios.